# Google Chrome rendering a glitchy overlay of horizontal lines and dots

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome renders a glitchy overlay of horizontal lines and dots, see screenshot in the link below.

Device: MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
Google Chrome: Version 84.0.4147.135 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I've tried restarting Chrome, ending the GPU-task in the builtin task manager. I've also tried deactivating all extensions and restarting the browser but the problem persists.

All websites does not trigger the behaviour but it is definitely a browser issue and not an issue with a specific website.

Has anyone experienced this and have a solution?

[image: Chrome Glitch]

Comment: Can you give an example of a website affected and one working normally? What happens on these sites in other browsers?

Comment: https://dribbble.com has the problem as well as https://laracasts.com, https://www.svd.se is working normally. In other browsers (Safari) all of these works as expected.